# Как заполнить pdf документ из данных формы?

Tags: javascript, frontend, pdf, acrobat

Есть форма на сайте. Пользователь заполняет её. Эти данные, из формы, вносятся в `pdf` файл в определенные места. Например, есть сертификат, готовый, в котором поле с ФИО пустое, пользователь вводит свое ФИО в input на сайте, и это ФИО попадает на сертификат в нужное место.

Как взаимодействовать с pdf форматом с помощью, например, `javascript`, или есть ли какое нибудь API для редоктирования `PDF` или `doc` форматов?

Answer (score 2):

Как я понял при помощи поиска, есть две стратегии:

**1. Создание нового документа.**

Вот в [этом](https://nastart-web.ru/blog/bitrixoid_notes/bitriks-php-i-tcpdf/) руководстве последовательно рассматриваются вопросы, начиная от подключения библиотеки, и заканчивая тем, как открывать сгенерированный документ в отдельном окне ajax'ом.

Вот эта [статья](https://habr.com/ru/post/31438/) на Хабре - довольно основательная, и на неё много ссылаются, но она уже старовата - это перевод 2008-го года.

Я мог бы скопировать код из этих руковоств в ответ, но, по моему, оригинальные статьи будут полезее.

**2. Использование темплейта, в котором будут заполнены тоько некоторые поля**

Это довольно несложный процесс, можно даже привести пример кода, котрый вписывает в документ фразу:

```
    <?
    $pdf = new FPDI(); 

    $pdf->setSourceFile('template.pdf'); 
    $tpl = $pdf->importPage(1); 
    $pdf->addPage(); 
    $pdf->useTemplate($tpl); <- template is imported

    $pdf->setXY(10, 20);
    $pdf->write(100, "Hi there"); <- write or draw something on the template

    $pdf->output('newpdf.pdf', 'D'); <- ready, save or output your pdf
    ?>
```

Вообще говоря, это просто пример кода с англоязычной части SO: "[Is there a solution for pdf template in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2849103/is-there-a-solution-for-pdf-template-in-php)"

Также, если у Вас возникнут более конкретные вопросы - милости просим, или welcome!

Comment: Спасибо вам что ответили на мой вопрос, но по этой ссылке показывалось как создовать документ pdf, а я бы хотел редоктировать уже существующий, внести данные пользователя из input в нужные места, как я могу это сделать

Comment: @fredded - справедливое замечание! я дополнил ответ. Не стесняйтесь задавать уточняющие вопросы.

Comment: а пользовались ли вы библиотекой jspdf, я не могу найти нормальной документации по современной версии этой библиотеки, хотел бы с помощью нее скачать свою html страницу в pdf

Comment: @fredded - нет, такой штукой, как jspdf я не пользовался, но я глянул на репу в гитхабе, и мне в целом понравилось. я бы при испоьзовании этой библиотеки просто перестал делать что то на серверной стороне, а вынес всю работу с pdf на клиента, просто реализовав на сервере rest api для доступа к шаблонам и к json-чикам с заполненными полями. Получилось бы изящное SPA-приложение

Comment: а как правильно заменить input на его значение? Есть несколько input ов, заполненные, и при нажатии кнопки мне нужно что бы все inputы заменились на их значения, как правильно это сделать с минимальным кодом

Comment: @fredded - я уверен, что там input'ы - именованные. Точно так же, как bookmarks в ворде. То есть, надо их просто заменять по имени.

Answer (score 0):

Я сейчас как раз пользуюсь jsPDF, для генерации PDF из того, что есть на экране (той же заполненной формы). Но документ на выходе получается достаточно "кривой", не все css3-фичи эта библиотека берет (тени, еще некоторые эффекты). В итоге на экране вроде и симпатично и адаптивно, а в документе ну как первоклассник сверстал :)

Я пробовал несколько подходов, но в итоге самый работающий оказался через некоторый "костыль":

```
 html2canvas(document.querySelector("#divMyQuestionnaire")).then(canvas => {
        let imgData = canvas.toDataURL("image/jpeg", 1.0);
        window.jsPDF = window.jspdf.jsPDF
        let pdf = new jsPDF({
            orientation: "landscape",
            unit: "in"
        });
        pdf.addImage(imgData, 'JPEG', 0, 0, 11, 7.8, "MEDIUM");
        pdf.save('Questionnaire_canvas.pdf')
    });
```

То есть генерирую canvas, и уже его как картинку скармливаю генератору.

Классический вариант типа:

```
window.jsPDF = window.jspdf.jsPDF
let pdf = new jsPDF()
let el = document.getElementById("divMyQuestionnaire")
await pdf.html(el, {
    callback: function(pdf) {
        pdf.save('Questionnaire_jsPDF.pdf')            }
})
```

отдавал то пустой документ (но на 2-3 страницы), то тексты в странной кодировке.